# GCP - Unable to access instance via SSH

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ssh, firewall

I am unable to access my VM instance on Google Cloud Platform and I have the issue isolated I believe to the VPC firewall rules. If I allow all ingress traffic (`0.0.0.0/0`) then obviously I can access the instance via SSH, however if I replace `0.0.0.0/0` with my exact IPv4 address, I receive the following:

> No ingress firewall rule allowing SSH found.
>
> If the project uses the default ingress firewall rule for SSH,
> connections to all VMs are allowed on TCP port 22. If the VPC network
> that the VM’s network interface is in has a custom firewall rule, make
> sure that the custom firewall rule allows ingress traffic on the VM’s
> SSH TCP port (usually, this is TCP port 22).

I get my IP address from browsing (whatsmyipaddress on Google) as well as the following below in terminal, so I know I have my IPv4 public IP address correct:

```
dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com
```

I am unsure as to why when I use my public IP address as 'allow ingress' to match on all ports with my exact IP, I am not allowed in, but a simple switch to `0.0.0.0/0` life is great. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: could you please provide a screenshot of  your firewall rule ? (you can mask your public ip)

Comment: What format did you provide for your IP address in the firewall rule?  It should be XX.XX.XX.XX/32 where the XX.XX.XX.XX is your actual IP address.

Comment: Have you tried what @Kolban mentioned on what format did you provide in your IP address in the firewall rule?

Comment: I have submitted a firewall screenshot showing the rule. I have ensured to isolate my public IPv4 address with a '/32' to denote a single IP in the provided range.

Comment: Additionally, I have ensured that my instance 'network' is pointing to the VPC with that particular subnet the firewall rule is attached to.  I literally don't have a solution quite yet.

Comment: I see, I suggest to perform connectivity test from your VM instance to your public IP and see what would be the result. Just make sure that the firewall is set to allow traffic to your public IP address. You can follow this [link](https://cloud.google.com/network-intelligence-center/docs/connectivity-tests/how-to/running-connectivity-tests#vm-to-non-cloud) as a guidance for connectivity test. Please also share with us the result once you perform the test.

Answer (score 0):

Seems as though when you connect by SSH using the browser, the IP address that instantiates the in-browser SSH connection is a Google IP, which seems to be the reason I am unable to connect, given the firewall rules I had set in place.

Comment: I was about to ask on how you connect to ssh and where did you run this command dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com. Glad to hear this one is already good.

Comment: what is the solution? I am facing same issue

Answer (score 0):

Following up on Andrew's comment, the IP address that instantiates the in-browser SSH connection is indeed a Google IP, hence not allowing the ssh connection to go through.

What you need to do is to connect to your GCP instance through your terminal on your local machine. After setting up the firewall rule on GCP, you need to generate an SSH Key Pair (ssh-keygen on Linux or macOS, or PuTTYgen on Windows). Make sure to write down the location of where the keys are stored on your local machine. After that, you will have to add the Public Key to the GCP instance that you are trying to connect to. You can do that by navigating to the edit section of the instance.

To connect to your GCP instance, you then have to use the ssh command alongside the previously generated private key:

```
ssh -i /path/to/private_key user@instance_public_ip
```

Hope this helps.